# Hybrid App Does not show WebView Context and Not able to Locate Element in App

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webview, appium, ionic-appflow

I am trying to Automate the Hybrid App. I am facing an issue with the Context. I am setting the app context

```
appiumdriver.context("WEBVIEW_appPackagename");
```

Now I was able to automate it previously. But I think the Webview changed and I am not able to Locate elements anymore. I have checked from appium UI view. It does config show like this.

This is what my View on Android Appium looks like.[image]

When I run the Sample Code of Locating Element. It's not working now. The same code was working previously. I have tried switching webview. But it does not help.

```
    appiumdriver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    //appiumdriver.context("WEBVIEW_com.barbri.nexgen");
    appiumdriver.context("WEBVIEW_1");
```

I have tried Like this both one by one. But it does not help. Capabilities are fine. Can anyone suggest to me any solution to? Its Hybrid Ionic app. I am asking this code after a lot of research.

Some Notes:
-Chrome inspect devices Do not show this app anymore for webview insepect.
-Appium shows as webview only. But not able to Locates Element anymore

Answer (score 1):

The first of all, try to know all available contexts in your app. Hope this [doc](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/get-contexts/) can help you.

The second way to fix your problem, launch app with web view as a default settings. You need to add field in desired capabilities:

```
{
 autoWebview: true,
}
```

More information about available desired capabilities [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).

Comment: Actually, we find out the issue from the App is that. It was an issue with the building app. The developer had switched off the flag of WebDebug.

Comment: Wow, the problem is less than thought. Nice to hear about the developer's help!